# ACCESS 2013 NOT criteria returns wrong values

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

OK, so guyes i have this table

[image]

the task is to get all the pets names which didn't take the Rabies Vaccine

so i made this query

`SELECT [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule].[Pet's Name]`

`FROM [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule], [Pet Vaccine]`

`WHERE ((Not ([Pets’ Vaccine Schedule].Vaccine)="Rabies"))`

`GROUP BY [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule].[Pet's Name];`

the problem is it shows everything ok, but it gives the pet name 'Bono' when it shouldn't , because Bono took the rabies vaccine as displayed in the last row. Can you help me with the query so it doesn't show Bono in the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish query to work on per name level, but in the reality it works on record level, it gives you Bono correctly as there is a record where vaccine isn't rabies (it's DHPP). You need to write a bit more complex query: `SELECT t1.petName FROM schedule as t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE vaccine ="rabies") AS t2 ON t1.petname = t2.petname WHERE t2.petname IS NULL GROUP BY t1.petname`

Comment: yep this is it...
hmm i was wondering on doing a more complex code, but this is an assignment from a university for economy classes i didn't think they would give complex code assignments

Comment: At least it should be `vaccine <> "rabies"` ? The solution itself depends on the table design, which is not exactly visible from your screenshot. There's a good chance that you can also get the correct result with an inner join like `SELECT [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule].ID, [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule].[Pet's Name], [Pet Vaccine].Vaccine
FROM [Pet Vaccine] INNER JOIN [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule] ON [Pet Vaccine].ID = [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule].Vaccine
WHERE ((([Pet Vaccine].Vaccine)<>'Rabies'));`

Comment: @Lonii Zenku: You can split the query into two more simple one so your solution won't be too complex for the economy class:). @Peter Schneider: To find out which pets haven't received the vaccine at first you need to list the ones received it, then exclude this list from the list of all pet names. So `="rabies"` is correct, the trick is the outer join and asking only for the records not matched in the second table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `NOT` you should use `<>`. So the correct query would be something like

```
SELECT [Pets' Vaccine Schedule].[Pet's Name]
FROM [Pets' Vaccine Schedule]
WHERE [Pets' Vaccine Schedule].Vaccine<>"Rabies"
GROUP BY [Pets' Vaccine Schedule].[Pet's Name];
```

Comment: I hope you have seen that I also changed the FROM Statement from above: `FROM [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule], [Pet Vaccine]` should be just `FROM  [Pets’ Vaccine Schedule]`. The answer definitly works...

Comment: yep, i saw that and corrected it at my querry, and still BONO shows up...i think it is because of the other rows where BONO is registered to take the other two vaccines, thus the record of NOT RABIES, but how do i eleminate that

Comment: My proposed solution above would work if the column Vaccine doesn't use another table...